# Replace of selected string from string

Tags: ios, swift

this is my whole string

"818 22nd St, West Palm Beach, FL 33407 2 bedrooms | 1 bath | CBS house Totally renovated | Everything new Rented for $1150 a month ASKING $94,000 CASH OR HARD MONEY Please note all offers are cash or hard money only (no mortgages cash offers only) Please note all offers are with zero contingencies (noRead more"

and I want to remove this part of the string

"818 22nd St, West Palm Beach, FL 33407 2 bedrooms |"

this are the solution I have used but no luck

first string is description and second is title and I want to remove title from description

```
    let string = properties!["description"]

    let removeString = properties!["title"]
    let newString = string?.replacingOccurrences(of: removeString, with: "")
    print(newString)
```

Comment: Your question makes little sense, you show us your input as a string but in your code you work with a dictionary? Furthermore you say that in that dictionary one item contains the whole string and another only the first part. Very confusing and I understand the downvotes.

Comment: i agree, on the first state of the question, but downvote and say nothing is not the right way ... so but it solved in the end :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well our question should have more informations. But for now, the correct anwser is ...

```
let string = "818 22nd St, West Palm Beach, FL 33407 2 bedrooms | 1 bath | CBS house Totally renovated | Everything new Rented for $1150 a month ASKING $94,000 CASH OR HARD MONEY Please note all offers are cash or hard money only (no mortgages cash offers only) Please note all offers are with zero contingencies (noRead more"

let removeString = "818 22nd St, West Palm Beach, FL 33407 2 bedrooms | "
let newString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: removString, with: "")
print(newString)
```

I could think about, that u try to remove the first section before the "|", but iam not really sure :)

Comment: than there might be something different in your code. can u post ur code? or your try? My Code did work, u can copy paste it into a playground and you will see

Comment: i see, the code is correct, but we cannot verify if the contents of the properties dictionary is correct. A wrong char, or a different whitspace character could lead to the not replaced string.
u should try to print the properties to the console, and verify if this really has the content as excpected